# How to handle unregistering of push notifications?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

Owning an Ionic application (cordova), I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to handle pushing of notifications.

I'm confused regarding the `unregister` function.

Reading the [official GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html):

> You should only need to unregister in rare cases, such as if you want
>   an app to stop receiving messages, or if you suspect that the
>   registration ID has been compromised. In general, once an app has a
>   registration ID, you shouldn't need to change it.

For those reasons:

> - A registration ID isn't associated with a particular logged in user.    If you unregister and then re-register, GCM may return the same ID or 
>     a different ID—there's no guarantee either way.
> - Unregistration may take up to 5 minutes to propagate.
> - After unregistration, re-registration may again take up to 5 minutes    to propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due
>     to the    state of being unregistered, and after all this, messages
>     may still    go to the wrong user.

**So I wonder why there is the functionality of unregistering client if this is really not recommended.**

Indeed, logically, by reading that, I think about implementing a custom unregister function at client side like the following pseudo-code:

```
function unregister() {
     deleteRegistrationIdFromServerDatabaseOnly();
}
```

=> no need to unregister the client itself.

Indeed, as it exists a mapping on the server database between `registrationId` and `userId`, by just emptying the `registrationId` value, no message would be sent to the client any more; what is expected.
Therefore, the only way to expect notifications again would be to let the client register again.

So, I repeat, what is the need/use case of unregistering the client itself?

It's really not clear.

Comment: You already put this in your question "You should only need to unregister in rare cases, such as if you want an app to stop receiving messages, or if you suspect that the registration ID has been compromised. In general, once an app has a registration ID, you shouldn't need to change it.". so  if you want an app to stop receiving messages, or if you suspect that the registration ID has been compromised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#unregister())

So I think the only use for unregister is if you want to change your sender id.   I am sure the id takes some resources on google servers as well so, it probably helps them if you unregister after removing the id from your server as well

> public void unregister ()
>
> Unregister the application. Calling unregister() stops any messages
>   from the server. This is a blocking call—you shouldn't call it from
>   the UI thread. You should rarely (if ever) need to call this method.
>   Not only is it expensive in terms of resources, but it invalidates
>   your registration ID, which you should never change unnecessarily. A
>   better approach is to simply have your server stop sending messages.
>   Only use unregister if you want to change your sender ID.
>
> Throws IOException    if we can't connect to server to unregister.